# Sending Proxy authentication Via Websocket to Proxy server

Tags: netty

I have a client who use Proxy to control client internet connection.
How can I pass user/pass authentication values in Websocket headers to the Proxy.

I'm using standard Netty implantation.

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    final String funcName = "messageReceived - ";
    try {
        Object msg = e.getMessage();
        logger.debug(funcName + msg + "class" + msg.getClass().getName());
        ThreadParams.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            handleHttpShakeHand(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
            // TaUtils.sleep(5000);
        } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
            handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error(funcName + "error: ", t);
    }
}

private void handleHttpShakeHand(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {

// Handshake
WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory wsFactory = new WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory(
        this.getWebSocketLocation(req), null, false);
this.handshaker = wsFactory.newHandshaker(req);
if (this.handshaker == null) {
    wsFactory.sendUnsupportedWebSocketVersionResponse(ctx.getChannel());
} else {
    this.handshaker.performOpeningHandshake(ctx.getChannel(), req);
}

return;
```

}

On the client I use Chrome's object to open the Websocket with the server.

```
ws = new WebSocket(localStorage["wsPath"]);
    ws.onclose = onClose;
    ws.onopen = onOpen;
    ws.onerror = onError;
```

Tamir

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Chrome configuration issue.

Try getting Chrome to use the proxy and configuring the user name and password in Chrome: http://googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-advanced-settings/Google-chrome-proxy-settings.html

Comment: This is excatly what we are doing but it's not working. How can I be certain the Shakehand on the server side truly return the Auth data in the Http headers?

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is to use SSL certificate to identify with the Proxy and by-pass Web socket authentication. 
Moving forward this is an open issue on clear text solution.